# CSS width max content in safari browser

Tags: html, css, safari, width

I've problem when styling my homepage. I have a div that I want to set the width based on the max content inside the div. Here the code

```
<div class="head">
    <div class="time"></div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Profile</li>
            <li>Gallery</li>
            <li>Location</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.head{
    position:relative;
    width: -moz-max-content;
    width: -webkit-max-content;
    width: -o-max-content;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.time{
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    left:0px;
    top:10px;
}
.logo{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:450px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.menu{
    position: absolute;
    width: -moz-max-content;
    width: -webkit-max-content;
    width: -o-max-content;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 210px;
}
```

Using `width: -moz-max-content`,`width: -webkit-max-content;` and `width: -o-max-content;` works well in chrome,opera and firefox. But it not working when I use safari to open the site. When I inspect the element from safari browser, it shown alert marks beside the `width: -webkit-max-content;` code style. It makes the width of the div same like 100%.

How can I set `width: max-content` in safari browser?

**UPDATE**

Same problem goes to `width: -moz-available;` and `width: -webkit-fill-available;` CSS code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set them to `display:inline-block` which will adjust to the `max-width` of inner content

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: left;
}
div.inlineblock {
  display: inline-block;
}
.align {
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>testing test</p>
</div>

<div class="align">
  <div class="inlineblock">
    <p>testing testing test</p>
    <p>testing testing</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. It's works well, but it remove the `margin:0px auto;` that I use to make the div right in the center.

Comment: just add `text-align:right` it will align the inline-block element to right @andy222 i have updated in the above snippet

Comment: I use `display:table` and it's working well. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: `inline-block` only adjusts to the width of its content if **the content is not wrapped**. Otherwise it will take the maximum available space like a `display:block` element.